# Switch active class when navigation links clicked jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add jQuery to a website so when the link to the next page in the nav menu is clicked, then "active" class is switched to the "active" or current page.  The "active" class is also set initially to the home page.  Additionally, it's a website using Bootstrap so I was wondering if something was conflicting with my jQuery.  Seems simple enough and my code works somewhat.  It removes the active class from the Home page and briefly flashes on the next tab, but it does not stay "active."  Here's the jQuery:

```
$(".nav li").click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Andrew

Comment: FYI, you can't interact with javascript between different tabs in browser. Another tab will be a completely new page, served separately. So if you need some logic added, pass a query parameter when opening a new link, so that the page code could distinguish which actions should be taken on load

Comment: As mentioned above, once you left a page, anything you manipulated in the dom is reverted. You should use an indicator, there are multiple ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  It didn't dawn on me going to a new page would revert back, but that makes sense in the way my code was behaving.  Thanks again for the little javascript lesson!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and wrote the following script:

```
var _urlpath = $(location).attr('pathname').split('/').pop();

    $('#menu > li').each(function(){
        var _this = $(this);
        var _str = _this.find('a').attr('href');
        _str !== _urlpath ? _this.removeClass('active') : _this.addClass('active');
    });
```

It's fairly simple: filter the url path name, store it in a variable, and then most importantly, when a new page is loaded, loop through all the li's and try and match the url hash (I don't know the exact terminology), hash in the li > a's .

Alas, there might be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, that helps a lot.  Like I said above, it didn't dawn on my going to a new page would "reset" the DOM, but it makes sense now.  I did think about using each() to loop through somehow, but again as far as getting the URL, not sure I would've thought about that.  Thanks for taking the time to respond and for the sample code.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Andrew no probs ! consider accepting the answer if it solves ur problem !

Comment: Yes, definitely.  The one thing I did notice is going straight to the URL doesn't add the 'active' class initially on page load to the home page, so I'll have to figure that out.  Could be because I have my .htaccess set to go directly to index.html and the javascript is looking for something else.  Other than that, it works great!